# Bootstrap 5 responsive buttons placement. How?

Tags: button, responsive, bootstrap-5

I have the following part of the form:

```
<div class="d-grid mb-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary mb-3" type="submit" name="userlogin">Login</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="window.location.href="/reset.php" name="rstpss">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Button `rstpss` is conditional and appears only in case user has entered wrong login or wrong password at the same time.

Both buttons currently use 100% of `div`'s width and placed strictly one below another.

But I want the `rstpss` button to be placed below the `userlogin` one only in case there is no available predefined `div`'s width to place them one next to another keeping in mind they both will take all available `div`'s width, be the same width and contain the same space between them as their bottom margins (the same margin is used with the `input` above the buttons).

When only `userlogin` button is shown it must take 100% `div`'s width.

I suppose it shouldn't be very difficult and must be clearly described at the Bootstripe's documentation, but I've started using Bootstrap just yesterday and just don't know what to look for. Any example I have found doesn't answer my question.

A clear example will help me greatly to understand how to deal with such cases in the future. And what to search at the Bootstrap's documentation, too.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: A visual example of my question]

Comment: I'm confused about what you trying to do. Can you clarify "I want the rstpss button to be placed below the userlogin one only in case there is no available predefined div's width to place them one next to another keeping in mind they both will take all available div's width, be the same width and contain the same space between them as their bottom margins"? Maybe it would be more apparent if you showed all the code like the "input above".

Comment: @Zim My English is certainly not enough to explain my question better that I did. I have attached a picture that demonstrates my aim.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="d-flex mb-3">
    <button class="btn btn-primary mb-3 flex-fill" type="submit" name="userlogin">Login</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mb-3 flex-fill" onclick="window.location.href="/reset.php" name="rstpss">Reset</button>
</div>
```

This should expand the first button to a 100% if the second one doesn't exist, and keep both buttons on same line with equal width if both exist.

Comment: Something is missing as both buttons keep staying next to each other in any circumstances. Also they are same size only in case their names don't exceed their sizes. Otherwise their sizes are different.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the following pile of tags. It does the job while it seems to be not the most elegant one.

```
<div class="row" style="--bs-gutter-x: 1rem">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="d-flex mb-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary flex-fill" style="white-space: nowrap;" type="submit" name="userlogin">Click or tap here to login</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="d-flex mb-3">
            <button class="btn btn-primary flex-fill" style="white-space: nowrap;" formaction="/reset.php" name="rstpss">Click or tap here to recover your password</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The default value of the `row` class is `1.5rem`. I have not found how to set the `row` class' size through predefined classes so I've made it `1rem` with inline style to make the horizontal space between two buttons equal to vertical space between the form's elements with `mb-3` class applied.

There is also inline style `white-space: nowrap` for the `button` tag to prevent its height growing instead of putting the long texted button to the next line.

I've used the first example from the Bootstrap's [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) except the outer `div` with the `container` class as it prevents achieving my goal.

My code still appear to me as an overproduced and incorrect one so I can't accept this answer as the answer.

The correct solution is still highly appreciated.